# What’s the most practical punctuation for this simple sentence?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, punctuation, writing-style, interjections, exclamations

I know this seems rudimentary, but it’s tripping me up for some reason.

> Yuck. Mushrooms are gross.

I feel the period creates to much of a pause and strays too far away from the emphasis I want on the “yuck”.

> Yuck, mushrooms are gross.

The comma, I’m assuming, will be the correct answer for most situations, but I’m admittedly not always proficient in them. I guess what’s slipping me up is that it kind of appears like a comma splice? “Yuck” can stand alone as its own sentence, and so can “mushrooms are gross”.

Or is the comma splice irrelevant in this case since the yuck acts more like an interjection or an introductory word/clause?

> Yuck: mushrooms are gross.

Any valid reason to ever use a colon with this sentence? I know that colons can be silently read as, “which is/are”, so it kind of would make sense in this case. I know the general rule with colons is that there must be an independent clauses preceding the colon for it to work. Yuck acts as an independent clause here, no?

> Yuck—mushrooms are gross.

Em dash? I know em dashes are very emphatic in nature. Writers choice here?

> Yuck; mushrooms are gross.

Semicolon? Similar to colons, I know that you need an independent clause preceding the semicolon for it work, but unlike colons, you also need an independent clause AFTERWARDS as well. Again, like the colon, does yuck act as an independent clause? Writers choice?

**Are any of these actually wrong?**

Comment: How does *practical* punctuation differ from plain ordinary punctuation?

Comment: Are we really about to nitpick and get into the semantics of a word that I frivolously chose? Don’t be that guy lol.

Comment: None of those is wrong, and you won’t have a comma splice if you go with the comma. Read about [minor sentences](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Major-and-Minor-Sentences-Regular-and-Irregular-Sentences.htm).

Comment: Awesome! Minor sentences is something I’ve never heard of before, and that link pretty much summed it up. Thanks for the help and actually answering my questions respectfully!

Answer (score 4):

“Yuck” as used, is an exclamation. So I suggest the one possibility missed — the exclamation mark!

> Yuck! Mushrooms are gross.

…unless the sentence refers to a brand of mushrooms, in which case no punctuation mark is required.

(The other thing wrong with the sentence is that mushrooms can be quite tasty, and only small children would refer to them as “gross”.)

Comment: Oh. I purposely missed that one on purpose. That’s too emphatic for me. That’s going to be a no from me lol. 

Also, what food people prefer don’t make them children. Even though I agree mushrooms taste good.

Comment: But not for me! It’s the users that vote on answers. The poster can accept or not, but generally he’s asking because he doesn’t know.

Comment: Yeah, It’s still going to be a no for me. Thanks for the feedback though.